# ANTLR visitor unit test succeeds on one rule but fails on another

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to define unit tests for my ANTLR parser.  The unit test successfully extracts the value of the first expr, but *fails* to extract the value of of the first idEscape.  This suggests that I am misunderstanding something core to the way in which the parser works, or the way in which visitors work.

I'm writing a parser for calculations in FileMaker Pro.  In FileMaker, it is technically valid for an identifier to contain whitespace as well as operators and other characters which would otherwise have a functional purpose in the calculation engine.  In those cases, the identifier is escaped by surrounding it with a '${' and '}'.  While the parser successfully identifies '${abcdef + 123}' as a valid expression, 
I still need to be able to identify 'abcdef + 123' as a valid identifier.  When I request the value of the first idEscape in a second unit test, I get an empty string.
If relevant, I'm using ANTLR4.Runtime.Standard.

What am I doing wrong?  Any assistance in resolving my misunderstanding would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

#### Grammar

```
grammar FileMakerCalc;  

// PARSER RULES

calculation :   expr;
expr        :   idEscExpr;
idEscExpr   :   LEFTESCAPE idEscape RIGHTESCAPE;
idEscape    :   (WORD|WS|OPERATOR|INT|FLOAT)*?;


// LEXER RULES

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;

LEFTESCAPE  :   '${';
RIGHTESCAPE :   '}';
OPERATOR    :   ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'&'|'^'|'='|'≠'|'<>'|'>'|'<'|'≤'|'<='|'≥'|'>=' );
WORD        :   (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE)+ ;
FLOAT       :   [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+;
INT         :   [0-9]+ ;
NEWLINE     :   [\r\n]+ ;
WS          :   [ \t];
```

#### Visitor

```
public class FileMakerCalcVisitor : FileMakerCalcBaseVisitor<String>
{


    public override string VisitExpr(FileMakerCalcParser.ExprContext context)
    {
        return context.GetText();
    }


    public override string VisitIdEscape(FileMakerCalcParser.IdEscapeContext context)
    {
        return context.GetText();
    }

}
```

#### Unit Tests

```
namespace Antler_Tests
{
    [TestFixture()]
    public class ParserTest
    {
        private FileMakerCalcParser Setup(string text)
        {
            AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(text);
            FileMakerCalcLexer lexer = new FileMakerCalcLexer(inputStream);
            CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            FileMakerCalcParser parser = new FileMakerCalcParser(commonTokenStream);

            return parser;
        }


        // This one successfully pulls '${abcdef + 123}' as the text of the first expr
        [Test()]
        public void EscapedID_CheckForExpr()
        {
            FileMakerCalcParser parser = Setup("${abcdef + 123}");

            FileMakerCalcParser.ExprContext context = parser.expr();
            FileMakerCalcVisitor visitor = new FileMakerCalcVisitor();

            var testVal = visitor.VisitExpr(context);

            Assert.AreEqual("${abcdef + 123}", testVal, testVal);
        }


        // This one does NOT successfully pull 'abcdef + 123' as the text of the first idEscape
        [Test()]
        public void EscapedID()
        {
            FileMakerCalcParser parser = Setup("${abcdef + 123}");

            FileMakerCalcParser.IdEscapeContext context = parser.idEscape();
            FileMakerCalcVisitor visitor = new FileMakerCalcVisitor();

            var testVal = visitor.VisitIdEscape(context);

            Assert.AreEqual("abcdef + 123", testVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${abcdef + 123}` is not a valid `idEscape` because it starts with `${` and ends with `}`, neither of which the `idEscape` rule accepts. The way you've defined it, `idEscape` only matches the stuff between `${}` and `idEscapeExpr` is the one that matches the whole thing.

So you'll want your test to either invoke the `idEscapeExpr` rule instead of `idEscape` or change the string you're parsing to `abcdef + 123` (or have one test for each).

Comment: But I'm trying to get the 'abcdef + 123' _portion_ of the '${abcdef + 123}' expression.  Shouldn't that be the idEscape, which I'm looking for in the second unit test?  Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: @DesignDB Yes, the `abcdef + 123` portion is the `idEscape`, but you're not accessing the `idEscape` of an `idEscapeExpr`. You're taking the input `${abcdef + 123}` and trying to parse that as an `idEscapeExpr`. You need to actually invoke a parser rule that matches the input. Then you can access the parts of the tree you get back in whichever way you want.

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  I've played with the code (local copy), and I think it's working now.  The issue was that some of my reading of code samples had suggested that a visitor could function as something of a query language, allowing me to parse the entire string, and then 'visit' only the elements that I care about.  Instead, the visitor indicates the grammar rule that should be applied to the string, and then I should deconstruct from there.  I knew this wasn't a typo, but a mistake in my understanding of the way that ANTLR and visitors work.  Thank you _very_ much for your assistance.

Comment: @DesignDB The visitor doesn't indicate what to parse (in fact I've pretty much ignored the visitor in my answer altogether because that's not where the problem was). The method you call on the parser object indicates what to parse. You're calling `parser.idEscape()` and that's why it tries to parse the input according to the `idEscape` rule. Since the input doesn't match that rule (and that rule can match an empty string because of the `*`), you get back an empty tree from that.

Comment: Your visitor is basically equivalent to just calling `GetText` on the given tree directly and doing so on an empty tree gives you an empty string. Also note that you basically never want to call `VisitIdEscape` etc. directly. You should just call the plain `Visit` method and it will call the appropriate `VisitFoo` method automatically. That's the point of the visitor pattern.